# View taking up whole screen when not desired

Tags: android

When I call setContentView with this view, it takes up the whole screen. I thought wrap_content and wrap_content would mean the view would be big enough to show the two strings only. I would like this to show just like a small dialog. Any ideas? How does an alert dialog use only the size that it needs? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="80dp"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:text="String 1"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_text1" 
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"                
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
         android:text="String 2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a programatic reason you are trying to reinvent the wheel?  Why not use a dialog?  The methods are all ready built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html for information on creating and using dialogs.